# Is it possible to perform integration test end to end in payment gateway (Magento 2.2)?

Tags: magento2.2, payment-methods, integration-test

The payment gateway which perform authorize and capture action by third party , Is it possible to perform integration test from  end to end , like start from build request to response and then success , complete application actions test inside **Vendor/ModuleName/Test/Integration** , any comment and reference link to solution will be appreciated.